# Open DrawerLayoutAndroid programmatically without string ref

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a Drawer class that sets the calls `setDrawer` prop in one of its components:

```
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid
    ref={drawer => this.props.setDrawer(drawer)}
  >
```

Then I have a parent component that sets `this.drawer`

```
    <Drawer setDrawer={(drawer) => { this.drawer = drawer; }} />
    <Menu drawer={this.drawer} />
```

Then in my `Menu` component, I have

```
this.props.drawer.openDrawer();
```

But `this.props.drawer` is always undefined.

What's the right way to do this?